# How to use PIC18f87k22 timer as interrupt

Tags: c, timer, embedded, pic, xc8

This is a generic question regarding the way to use timer0 on PIC.

I'm trying to build a dc motor control system using a PIC18f87k22 and an arduino pro trinket.

In my program, I have a function called `get_courant()`.
This function sends requests to the trinket and reads the answer received (by uart) and stores that value in one of my global variables, thus actualizing it.

What I would like to do is use the timer as follows:

If `get_courant()` takes more than 10us to proceed, then skip it, and go directly to the rest of the instructions in my main.

I know I'm supposed to start a timer before calling the function, and somehow read the timer value to decide rather to skip it or not.

However, if I check the timer value *after* the function is called, then my time could be waisted if the execution of `get_courant() exceeded 10us, in which case the timer is useless.

Any tip to help me realize what I want to achieve (IDK if that was clear with my bad english)? 
Here is the code of `get_courant()` if that can be of any help:

```
int16_t get_courant()
{
 uint8_t courant1;
 uint8_t courant2;
 int16_t courant;

 if(EUSART1_is_tx_ready())
        {
            EUSART1_Write(0b00000001);
        }
 if(EUSART1_is_rx_ready())
        {
        courant1= EUSART1_Read(); 
        }

 if(EUSART1_is_tx_ready())
        {
            EUSART1_Write(0b00000010);
        }
 if(EUSART1_is_rx_ready())
        {
        courant2= EUSART1_Read(); 
        }
 if (CheckBit(courant1,7))
 {
    bit_clr(courant1,7);
    courant = (courant1 << 8) | courant2;
    courant = - courant;
 }
 else 
 {
    courant = (courant1 << 8) | courant2;
 }

 return courant;   
 }
```

and this is the part of my main function where I call get_courant() :

```
while(!Stop_flag)
{   
    int i=0;
    do
    {


        Mesure_courant=get_courant();
        Tension_initiale = PID_Courant(Mesure_courant,Erreur_courant,Consigne_courant,Integrale_courant,Kp_courant,Ki_courant,Kd_courant,Wind_up_flag_courant);
        i++;
        Put_Rapport_Cyclique(Tension_initiale, Choix_Mode);

    } while(i<10);
```

Comment: Since there is no wait condition in `get_courant()` function, and that you check always that something is readable on UART before reading it, the execution time of `get_courant()` should be constant, isn't?

Comment: That should be the case indeed, however I have to consider that my trinket can possibly be busy (lots of interrupts there) and thus cannot answer in time !

Answer (score 1):

according to PIC18f87k22 datasheet page 193 in T0CON register's 7th bit TMR0ON is activating the timer to count or stop it.
Respect to that u can set that TMR0ON in the function that u want to measure the staying time and check the 10uS and u gotta reset it after u leave the function(in 10uS or after 10uS in anyway) u should also make sure after Clearing TMR0ON or before seting TMR0ON u must clean the old value that timer hold to not affect from previous measurement

Comment: So you are suggesting me to start the timer **inside** my get_courant() function, then check inside of that function (for example before every if) if the timer exeeded 10Us ?   Woudn't that condiderably slower my code ? This function is supposed to get cqlled 1000 times per sec.